# Weird characters displayed when importing WordPress MySQL db

Tags: mysql, import, characters

I was thinking that it may be the collation, but I have no way of know what the production db collation is. The local one has been changed between UTF8_bin and UTF8_general_ci, to no avail. I'm seeing characters like á and what looks like a capital T, but maybe in subscript form.

I've also checked the data that's imported and saw that the original data contains things like a space before a `</strong>`, at least I think it's a space.

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try setting the DB Charset within `wp-config.php`?

`define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8_general_ci');`

`define('DB_COLLATE', 'utf8_general_ci');`

Have a read of this first though: https://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php

It can cause problems to an already existing blog to add those lines into `wp-config.php`, so use with caution.

Are you importing this through WordPress or manually through something like PhpMyAdmin?

Also, are all the tables are collated correctly?

Comment: The DB is imported to a db with same dbname/username/password. As for the config file, the charset is set to utf8, but the db_collate is left blank. I think there's a comment saying to leave it alone if you're not sure anyways.